# Joining Tables w/out foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Is it possible to connect tables without foreign key?
For example

tblstudent
Columns:

1. id
2. firstname
3. lastname
4. middlename

tblgrade
Comluns:

1. id
2. quiz
3. project
4. exam

tblfinalgrade
Columns:

1. firstname
2. lastname
3. finalgrade

   Is it possible to view final grade when searching for and id?

Comment: because of there is no reference, you have to match firstname and lastname of tblstudent and tblfinalgrade.

Comment: is it possible when the keyword im searching is the value of "id"?

Answer (score 1):

The id in `tblStudent` is meaningless because you are not referencing it in your other tables.  Change your table structure to include this `StudentId` rather than `First Name` and `Last Name`.

For example:

**tblGrade**

columns:

- GradeId
- StudentId
- Quiz
- Project
- Exam

**tblFinalGrade**

- FinalGradeId
- StudentId
- FinalGrade

You can then do:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LAstName, Quiz, Project, Exam, FinalGrade
FROM tblStudent
INNER JOIN tblGrade ON tblGrade.StudentId = tblStudent.StudentId
INNER JOIN tblFinalGrade ON tblFinalGrade.StudentId = tblStudent.StudentId
```

This would be a better structure than joining on `FirstName` and `Last Name` just incase you ever have 5 `John Smith` how do you know you are returning the correct grades?

Although I am slightly against your original design, you can perform the same query with your existing structure by running the following query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LAstName, Quiz, Project, Exam, FinalGrade
FROM tblStudent
INNER JOIN tblFinalGrade ON tblFinalGrade.FirstName = tblStudent.FirstName AND  tblFinalGrade.LastName = tblStudent.LastName
WHERE tblStudent.ID = 1
```

Comment: i forgot to add id in tblgrade,sorry

Comment: @NewInJava - you'd still have to have a link between Grade and Student and Final Grade and Student.  The structure I've provided would be more suitable.

Comment: -actually that is my problem i am using a database exactly like that(i didn't create). is it possible to view the final grade of a certain student from tblfinalgrade referring to the firstname from the tblstudent when i search "id" ?

Comment: @NewInJava - I've modified my answer to show you how to JOIN on FirstName and LastName with an ID.  However what you have isn't correct database design.

Comment: what if tblFinalGrade doesnt have the column StudentId, can i still connect it to the two other tables? I'm just instructed to use the database so i have no choice but to use it.

Comment: @NewInJava - I've shown you how to do that in my answer... please reread it. The part I've added doesn't use StudentID it just uses `ID` from tblStudent.

Comment: let me revise my question, what if there's no field name FirstName on the tblFinalGrade but have a field name strFirstName?

Comment: @NewInJava - then change the JOIN to specify strFirstName rather than FirstName.... I can only go on the information you provide me in your question.